# Data for teaching: Representative simple random sample in educational research

Tags: data-request, education

I´m searching for a gripping data set from educational research which is

- a simple random sample (and therefore without weights)
- representative
- and available as public-usefile

to use for teaching. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I`m teaching introductory statistics to undergrats, which are (student) teachers.
Representative means, that the demographic covariates of the sample are equally distributed to the population.

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear, please [edit] it. What is *representative*? What should be the sample size? In what format? Why *gripping* (says nothing)? For teaching *what*? Why *from educational research*? Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) to improve your question.

Comment: is this an oer question?

Comment: Please bear in mind that this is an international website and specify the country/education system you would like the data set to be representative of.

Answer (score 1):

Since you go with statistical analysis, I recommend the R-Datasets. They are usually small and statistically interesting: 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html

They are not necessarily representative in a bigger context, but they represent one given experiment/survey.

Famous datasets my lecturers used for statistics are: Iris, Titanic, MTCars, Anscombe

EDIT similar question:
[Data sets for teaching](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/data-sets-for-teaching?rq=1)

Comment: Thank's for this answer. I'm already aware of these datasets and think it is great that they are implemented into R. Nevertheless I understand my students who say "I'm not interested in the distribution of petals length, I'm interested in the distribution of student's literacy and it's relation to ....".